# AES key derivation

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

What is the correct (acceptable) way to derive an, lets say 128 bit AES key from the secret derived in a DH negotiation?

- Use the first 128 bit
- Hash the secret and use the first 128 bit
- Use some more complicated derivation function

How would you derive a set of keys in a "correct" manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, in TLS used pseudo-random function, which is based on SHA1 and MD5 hash over shared secret (i.e. DH key exchange value), string label (to distinguish different cases for which key is generated, HMAC, cipher and so on), and shared random parameter (both client and server generates his own half of random parameter).

So, i'd recommend to add some random data generated by both client and server, and hash it together with DH key exchange value.

Comment: So, sha256 ( DH secret || usage string || random A || random B), first 128 bit would be suitable for an AES key? Why should we add an additional negotiation round trip for the new random?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough. Random data doesn't need another round trip, since it can be sent along with other key exchange-related data. That's for protection from some king of attacks, i'm not remember for sure from which ones.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a standard. One such standard is [NIST Special Pub 800-56A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56A/SP800-56A_Revision1_Mar08-2007.pdf). See in particular section 5.8.

Comment: I'm looking for the step after this one. I've negotiated a secret based on DH. Now i must derive a symmetric cipher key, based on this material. Whats the best way?

Comment: Section 5.8 of this standard has what you need.